# $q.all invokation issue in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, q

It is more of an implementation issue. 
I am not sure what have I done wrong.

```
var promises = items.map(function(item) {
        return HttpWrapper.send(url, {"operation": 'GET'}).then(function(pricingOptions) {
            item.selectedItem = pricingOptions[0];
            item.selectedItem.zone = 'us-east-1a'; 
            arr.push(item);
        });    
});
$q.all(promises).then(function(result) {
    vm.selectedItems.server = arr;
```

But the problem is ...

it resolves first and comes to ...

```
item.selectedItem = pricingOptions[0];
item.selectedItem.zone = 'us-east-1a';
```

It should be coming inside `$q.all` right? Or can I remove `$q.all()` altogether.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is there an `else` statement after the map function? Also, how does the HttpWrapper look like?

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro else is not necessary and HttpWrapper can be assumed as $http

Comment: Consider adding an error callback to the allPromise like, `$q.all(promises).then(function(result) {...}, console.error);`, because one of your promises might not be resolving.

Answer (score 0):

```
var promises = items.map(function(item) {
        return HttpWrapper.send(url, {"operation": 'GET'}).then(function(pricingOptions) {
            item.selectedItem = pricingOptions[0];
            item.selectedItem.zone = 'us-east-1a'; 
            return item;
        });    
});
$q.all(promises).then(function(result) {
    vm.selectedItems.server = result;
```